# Batch api call using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

Is there a way to create a batch api request with different access tokens to be used?
I need to crawl data from youtube channel using the offline access tokens of our users but the problem is we have 20K of that and having 1 request at a time is really painful and is taking lot of time.